# Toggle disable with if statement

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, radio-button

So I am having trouble with this disable stuff. I am trying to toddle a disable with an IF statement and radio buttons. I have tried with out an if with no success. Please help if you can! My code is as follows.

```
<html>
<h1>Convert Temperature</h1>
<body>
<input id="example" type="radio" onClick="toggle('example', 'disableMe')" name="Radio" value="Radio"> 
From Fahrenheit to Celsius </br>
<input id="example" type="radio" onClick="toggle('example', 'disableMe')" name="Radio" value="Radio"> From Celsius to Fahrenheit
</br>
</br>
</br>
<form name="converter">
Celsius: <input id="disableMe" type="text" name="celsius" onChange="CelsiusConverter()"><br />
Fahrenheit: <input id="disableMe" type="text" name="fahrenheit" onChange="FahrenheitConverter()"><br />
<input type="button" value="Convert!" />
</form>
</body>
<script language="JavaScript">
<!--
function CelsiusConverter(){
document.converter.fahrenheit.value = (document.converter.celsius.value * 9 / 5) + 32
}
function FahrenheitConverter(){
document.converter.celsius.value = (document.converter.fahrenheit.value - 32) * 5 / 9
}
//-->
function toggle(radioID, toggleID) { 
var radio = document.getElementById(radioID); 
var toggle = document.getElementById(toggleID); 
updateToggle = radio.checked ? toggle.disabled=true : toggle.disabled=false;

if (radioID = checked)
{
toggle.disable=true;
}
}
</script>
</html>
```

I know that the IF i have in there doesn't look right and something need to be fix but i don't know how!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- To be picky you should prefer === to == for comparison.
- You should also aim for id's to be unique in your page.
- change `<script language="javscript"` to `<script type="text/javascript"`
- What do you expect the value of `checked` to be in your comparison?
- jQuery would help you here

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Will be sure to make the changes.

Answer (score 1):

```
 if (radioID = checked) {
toggle.disable=true;
}
```

Should be

```
if(radioID == checked) {
toggle.disable = true;
}
```

Because you are not assigning the value of checked to radioID (=), but comparing the two (==).

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with the code.  Here's one that works for me, with some simplifications:

First, change your controls so they have different IDs and onClicks:

```
<input id="example1" type="radio" onClick="toggle(1)" name="Radio" value="Radio"> 
...
<input id="example2" type="radio" onClick="toggle(2)" name="Radio" value="Radio">
...
<input id="disableMe1" type="text" name="celsius" onChange="CelsiusConverter()">
...
<input id="disableMe2" type="text" name="fahrenheit" onChange="FahrenheitConverter()">
...
```

Finally, code this as your toggle function:

```
function toggle(id) { 
var base = 'disableMe';
var disable = document.getElementById(base+id); 
var enable = document.getElementById(base+(id == 1 ? 2 : 1));
disable.disabled = true;
enable.disabled = false;
}
```